# How to implement Dirichlet distribution formula in php

Tags: php

[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SbBR.jpg)

From the above, I want to find the dirichlet distribution, variables are listed in the picture.

I got probability calculation formula From this, I want to find the next step that is Dirichlet distribution.

```
function weighted_random($values, $weights) {  
    $count = count($values); 
    $i = 0; 
    $n = 0; 
    $num = mt_rand(0, array_sum($weights)); 

    while($i < $count) {
        $n += $weights[$i]; 

        if($n >= $num) {
            break; 
        }

        $i++; 
    } 

    return $values[$i]; 
}
```